# Disabled getmypid() on shared host

Tags: php, laravel-4, swiftmailer

I've problem with **swiftmailer** on a **shared host**, it uses `getmypid()` to generate random strings but `getmypid()` is disabled

```
'getmypid() has been disabled for security reasons' in /home/.../laravel4/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Mime/SimpleMimeEntity.php
```

what should I do? can I replace getmypid() with something else?

here is the whole file

```
/*
 * This file is part of SwiftMailer.
 * (c) 2004-2009 Chris Corbyn
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

/**
 * A MIME entity, in a multipart message.
 *
 * @package    Swift
 * @subpackage Mime
 * @author     Chris Corbyn
 */

class Swift_Mime_SimpleMimeEntity implements Swift_Mime_MimeEntity
{
    /** A collection of Headers for this mime entity */
    private $_headers;

/** The body as a string, or a stream */
private $_body;

/** The encoder that encodes the body into a streamable format */
private $_encoder;

/** The grammar to use for id validation */
private $_grammar;

/** A mime boundary, if any is used */
private $_boundary;

/** Mime types to be used based on the nesting level */
private $_compositeRanges = array(
    'multipart/mixed' => array(self::LEVEL_TOP, self::LEVEL_MIXED),
    'multipart/alternative' => array(self::LEVEL_MIXED, self::LEVEL_ALTERNATIVE),
    'multipart/related' => array(self::LEVEL_ALTERNATIVE, self::LEVEL_RELATED)
);

/** A set of filter rules to define what level an entity should be nested at */
private $_compoundLevelFilters = array();

/** The nesting level of this entity */
private $_nestingLevel = self::LEVEL_ALTERNATIVE;

/** A KeyCache instance used during encoding and streaming */
private $_cache;

/** Direct descendants of this entity */
private $_immediateChildren = array();

/** All descendants of this entity */
private $_children = array();

/** The maximum line length of the body of this entity */
private $_maxLineLength = 78;

/** The order in which alternative mime types should appear */
private $_alternativePartOrder = array(
    'text/plain' => 1,
    'text/html' => 2,
    'multipart/related' => 3
);

/** The CID of this entity */
private $_id;

/** The key used for accessing the cache */
private $_cacheKey;

protected $_userContentType;

/**
 * Create a new SimpleMimeEntity with $headers, $encoder and $cache.
 *
 * @param Swift_Mime_HeaderSet      $headers
 * @param Swift_Mime_ContentEncoder $encoder
 * @param Swift_KeyCache            $cache
 * @param Swift_Mime_Grammar        $grammar
 */
public function __construct(Swift_Mime_HeaderSet $headers, Swift_Mime_ContentEncoder $encoder, Swift_KeyCache $cache, Swift_Mime_Grammar $grammar)
{
    $this->_cacheKey = md5(uniqid(getmypid().mt_rand(), true));
    $this->_cache = $cache;
    $this->_headers = $headers;
    $this->_grammar = $grammar;
    $this->setEncoder($encoder);
    $this->_headers->defineOrdering(array('Content-Type', 'Content-Transfer-Encoding'));

    // This array specifies that, when the entire MIME document contains
    // $compoundLevel, then for each child within $level, if its Content-Type
    // is $contentType then it should be treated as if it's level is
    // $neededLevel instead.  I tried to write that unambiguously! :-\
    // Data Structure:
    // array (
    //   $compoundLevel => array(
    //     $level => array(
    //       $contentType => $neededLevel
    //     )
    //   )
    // )

    $this->_compoundLevelFilters = array(
        (self::LEVEL_ALTERNATIVE + self::LEVEL_RELATED) => array(
            self::LEVEL_ALTERNATIVE => array(
                'text/plain' => self::LEVEL_ALTERNATIVE,
                'text/html' => self::LEVEL_RELATED
                )
            )
        );

    $this->_id = $this->getRandomId();
}

/**
 * Generate a new Content-ID or Message-ID for this MIME entity.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function generateId()
{
    $this->setId($this->getRandomId());

    return $this->_id;
}

/**
 * Get the {@link Swift_Mime_HeaderSet} for this entity.
 *
 * @return Swift_Mime_HeaderSet
 */
public function getHeaders()
{
    return $this->_headers;
}

/**
 * Get the nesting level of this entity.
 *
 * @see LEVEL_TOP, LEVEL_MIXED, LEVEL_RELATED, LEVEL_ALTERNATIVE
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getNestingLevel()
{
    return $this->_nestingLevel;
}

/**
 * Get the Content-type of this entity.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getContentType()
{
    return $this->_getHeaderFieldModel('Content-Type');
}

/**
 * Set the Content-type of this entity.
 *
 * @param string $type
 *
 * @return Swift_Mime_SimpleMimeEntity
 */
public function setContentType($type)
{
    $this->_setContentTypeInHeaders($type);
    // Keep track of the value so that if the content-type changes automatically
    // due to added child entities, it can be restored if they are later removed
    $this->_userContentType = $type;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get the CID of this entity.
 *
 * The CID will only be present in headers if a Content-ID header is present.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->_headers->has($this->_getIdField()) ? current((array) $this->_getHeaderFieldModel($this->_getIdField())) : $this->_id;
}

/**
 * Set the CID of this entity.
 *
 * @param string $id
 *
 * @return Swift_Mime_SimpleMimeEntity
 */
public function setId($id)
{
    if (!$this->_setHeaderFieldModel($this->_getIdField(), $id)) {
        $this->_headers->addIdHeader($this->_getIdField(), $id);
    }
    $this->_id = $id;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get the description of this entity.
 *
 * This value comes from the Content-Description header if set.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getDescription()
{
    return $this->_getHeaderFieldModel('Content-Description');
}

/**
 * Set the description of this entity.
 *
 * This method sets a value in the Content-ID header.
 *
 * @param string $description
 *
 * @return Swift_Mime_SimpleMimeEntity
 */
public function setDescription($description)
{
    if (!$this->_setHeaderFieldModel('Content-Description', $description)) {
        $this->_headers->addTextHeader('Content-Description', $description);
    }

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get the maximum line length of the body of this entity.
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getMaxLineLength()
{
    return $this->_maxLineLength;
}

/**
 * Set the maximum line length of lines in this body.
 *
 * Though not enforced by the library, lines should not exceed 1000 chars.
 *
 * @param integer $length
 *
 * @return Swift_Mime_SimpleMimeEntity
 */
public function setMaxLineLength($length)
{
    $this->_maxLineLength = $length;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get all children added to this entity.
 *
 * @return array of Swift_Mime_Entity
 */
public function getChildren()
{
    return $this->_children;
}

/**
 * Set all children of this entity.
 *
 * @param array   $children      Swift_Mime_Entity instances
 * @param integer $compoundLevel For internal use only
 *
 * @return Swift_Mime_SimpleMimeEntity
 */
public function setChildren(array $children, $compoundLevel = null)
{
    // TODO: Try to refactor this logic

    $compoundLevel = isset($compoundLevel)
        ? $compoundLevel
        : $this->_getCompoundLevel($children)
        ;

    $immediateChildren = array();
    $grandchildren = array();
    $newContentType = $this->_userContentType;

    foreach ($children as $child) {
        $level = $this->_getNeededChildLevel($child, $compoundLevel);
        if (empty($immediateChildren)) { //first iteration
            $immediateChildren = array($child);
        } else {
            $nextLevel = $this->_getNeededChildLevel($immediateChildren[0], $compoundLevel);
            if ($nextLevel == $level) {
                $immediateChildren[] = $child;
            } elseif ($level < $nextLevel) {
                // Re-assign immediateChildren to grandchildren
                $grandchildren = array_merge($grandchildren, $immediateChildren);
                // Set new children
                $immediateChildren = array($child);
            } else {
                $grandchildren[] = $child;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!empty($immediateChildren)) {
        $lowestLevel = $this->_getNeededChildLevel($immediateChildren[0], $compoundLevel);

        // Determine which composite media type is needed to accommodate the
        // immediate children
        foreach ($this->_compositeRanges as $mediaType => $range) {
            if ($lowestLevel > $range[0]
                && $lowestLevel <= $range[1])
            {
                $newContentType = $mediaType;
                break;
            }
        }

        // Put any grandchildren in a subpart
        if (!empty($grandchildren)) {
            $subentity = $this->_createChild();
            $subentity->_setNestingLevel($lowestLevel);
            $subentity->setChildren($grandchildren, $compoundLevel);
            array_unshift($immediateChildren, $subentity);
        }
    }

    $this->_immediateChildren = $immediateChildren;
    $this->_children = $children;
    $this->_setContentTypeInHeaders($newContentType);
    $this->_fixHeaders();
    $this->_sortChildren();

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get the body of this entity as a string.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getBody()
{
    return ($this->_body instanceof Swift_OutputByteStream)
        ? $this->_readStream($this->_body)
        : $this->_body;
}

/**
 * Set the body of this entity, either as a string, or as an instance of
 * {@link Swift_OutputByteStream}.
 *
 * @param mixed  $body
 * @param string $contentType optional
 *
 * @return Swift_Mime_SimpleMimeEntity
 */
public function setBody($body, $contentType = null)
{
    if ($body !== $this->_body) {
        $this->_clearCache();
    }

    $this->_body = $body;
    if (isset($contentType)) {
        $this->setContentType($contentType);
    }

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get the encoder used for the body of this entity.
 *
 * @return Swift_Mime_ContentEncoder
 */
public function getEncoder()
{
    return $this->_encoder;
}

/**
 * Set the encoder used for the body of this entity.
 *
 * @param Swift_Mime_ContentEncoder $encoder
 *
 * @return Swift_Mime_SimpleMimeEntity
 */
public function setEncoder(Swift_Mime_ContentEncoder $encoder)
{
    if ($encoder !== $this->_encoder) {
        $this->_clearCache();
    }

    $this->_encoder = $encoder;
    $this->_setEncoding($encoder->getName());
    $this->_notifyEncoderChanged($encoder);

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get the boundary used to separate children in this entity.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getBoundary()
{
    if (!isset($this->_boundary)) {
        $this->_boundary = '_=_swift_v4_' . time() . '_' . md5(getmypid().mt_rand().uniqid('', true)) . '_=_';
    }

    return $this->_boundary;
}

/**
 * Set the boundary used to separate children in this entity.
 *
 * @param string $boundary
 *
 * @return Swift_Mime_SimpleMimeEntity
 *
 * @throws Swift_RfcComplianceException
 */
public function setBoundary($boundary)
{
    $this->_assertValidBoundary($boundary);
    $this->_boundary = $boundary;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Receive notification that the charset of this entity, or a parent entity
 * has changed.
 *
 * @param string $charset
 */
public function charsetChanged($charset)
{
    $this->_notifyCharsetChanged($charset);
}

/**
 * Receive notification that the encoder of this entity or a parent entity
 * has changed.
 *
 * @param Swift_Mime_ContentEncoder $encoder
 */
public function encoderChanged(Swift_Mime_ContentEncoder $encoder)
{
    $this->_notifyEncoderChanged($encoder);
}

/**
 * Get this entire entity as a string.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function toString()
{
    $string = $this->_headers->toString();
    $string .= $this->_bodyToString();

    return $string;
}

/**
 * Get this entire entity as a string.
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function _bodyToString()
{
    $string = '';

    if (isset($this->_body) && empty($this->_immediateChildren)) {
        if ($this->_cache->hasKey($this->_cacheKey, 'body')) {
            $body = $this->_cache->getString($this->_cacheKey, 'body');
        } else {
            $body = "\r\n" . $this->_encoder->encodeString($this->getBody(), 0,
                $this->getMaxLineLength()
                );
            $this->_cache->setString($this->_cacheKey, 'body', $body,
                Swift_KeyCache::MODE_WRITE
                );
        }
        $string .= $body;
    }

    if (!empty($this->_immediateChildren)) {
        foreach ($this->_immediateChildren as $child) {
            $string .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $this->getBoundary() . "\r\n";
            $string .= $child->toString();
        }
        $string .= "\r\n\r\n--" . $this->getBoundary() . "--\r\n";
    }

    return $string;
}

/**
 * Returns a string representation of this object.
 *
 * @see toString()
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->toString();
}

/**
 * Write this entire entity to a {@see Swift_InputByteStream}.
 *
 * @param Swift_InputByteStream
 */
public function toByteStream(Swift_InputByteStream $is)
{
    $is->write($this->_headers->toString());
    $is->commit();

    $this->_bodyToByteStream($is);
}

/**
 * Write this entire entity to a {@link Swift_InputByteStream}.
 *
 * @param Swift_InputByteStream
 */
protected function _bodyToByteStream(Swift_InputByteStream $is)
{
    if (empty($this->_immediateChildren)) {
        if (isset($this->_body)) {
            if ($this->_cache->hasKey($this->_cacheKey, 'body')) {
                $this->_cache->exportToByteStream($this->_cacheKey, 'body', $is);
            } else {
                $cacheIs = $this->_cache->getInputByteStream($this->_cacheKey, 'body');
                if ($cacheIs) {
                    $is->bind($cacheIs);
                }

                $is->write("\r\n");

                if ($this->_body instanceof Swift_OutputByteStream) {
                    $this->_body->setReadPointer(0);

                    $this->_encoder->encodeByteStream($this->_body, $is, 0, $this->getMaxLineLength());
                } else {
                    $is->write($this->_encoder->encodeString($this->getBody(), 0, $this->getMaxLineLength()));
                }

                if ($cacheIs) {
                    $is->unbind($cacheIs);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (!empty($this->_immediateChildren)) {
        foreach ($this->_immediateChildren as $child) {
            $is->write("\r\n\r\n--" . $this->getBoundary() . "\r\n");
            $child->toByteStream($is);
        }
        $is->write("\r\n\r\n--" . $this->getBoundary() . "--\r\n");
    }
}

// -- Protected methods

/**
 * Get the name of the header that provides the ID of this entity
 */
protected function _getIdField()
{
    return 'Content-ID';
}

/**
 * Get the model data (usually an array or a string) for $field.
 */
protected function _getHeaderFieldModel($field)
{
    if ($this->_headers->has($field)) {
        return $this->_headers->get($field)->getFieldBodyModel();
    }
}

/**
 * Set the model data for $field.
 */
protected function _setHeaderFieldModel($field, $model)
{
    if ($this->_headers->has($field)) {
        $this->_headers->get($field)->setFieldBodyModel($model);

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Get the parameter value of $parameter on $field header.
 */
protected function _getHeaderParameter($field, $parameter)
{
    if ($this->_headers->has($field)) {
        return $this->_headers->get($field)->getParameter($parameter);
    }
}

/**
 * Set the parameter value of $parameter on $field header.
 */
protected function _setHeaderParameter($field, $parameter, $value)
{
    if ($this->_headers->has($field)) {
        $this->_headers->get($field)->setParameter($parameter, $value);

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Re-evaluate what content type and encoding should be used on this entity.
 */
protected function _fixHeaders()
{
    if (count($this->_immediateChildren)) {
        $this->_setHeaderParameter('Content-Type', 'boundary',
            $this->getBoundary()
            );
        $this->_headers->remove('Content-Transfer-Encoding');
    } else {
        $this->_setHeaderParameter('Content-Type', 'boundary', null);
        $this->_setEncoding($this->_encoder->getName());
    }
}

/**
 * Get the KeyCache used in this entity.
 *
 * @return Swift_KeyCache
 */
protected function _getCache()
{
    return $this->_cache;
}

/**
 * Get the grammar used for validation.
 *
 * @return Swift_Mime_Grammar
 */
protected function _getGrammar()
{
    return $this->_grammar;
}

/**
 * Empty the KeyCache for this entity.
 */
protected function _clearCache()
{
    $this->_cache->clearKey($this->_cacheKey, 'body');
}

/**
 * Returns a random Content-ID or Message-ID.
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function getRandomId()
{
    $idLeft = md5(getmypid() . '.' . time() . '.' . uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
    $idRight = !empty($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) ? $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] : 'swift.generated';
    $id = $idLeft . '@' . $idRight;

    try {
        $this->_assertValidId($id);
    } catch (Swift_RfcComplianceException $e) {
        $id = $idLeft . '@swift.generated';
    }

    return $id;
}

// -- Private methods

private function _readStream(Swift_OutputByteStream $os)
{
    $string = '';
    while (false !== $bytes = $os->read(8192)) {
        $string .= $bytes;
    }

    return $string;
}

private function _setEncoding($encoding)
{
    if (!$this->_setHeaderFieldModel('Content-Transfer-Encoding', $encoding)) {
        $this->_headers->addTextHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding', $encoding);
    }
}

private function _assertValidBoundary($boundary)
{
    if (!preg_match(
        '/^[a-z0-9\'\(\)\+_\-,\.\/:=\?\ ]{0,69}[a-z0-9\'\(\)\+_\-,\.\/:=\?]$/Di',
        $boundary))
    {
        throw new Swift_RfcComplianceException('Mime boundary set is not RFC 2046 compliant.');
    }
}

private function _setContentTypeInHeaders($type)
{
    if (!$this->_setHeaderFieldModel('Content-Type', $type)) {
        $this->_headers->addParameterizedHeader('Content-Type', $type);
    }
}

private function _setNestingLevel($level)
{
    $this->_nestingLevel = $level;
}

private function _getCompoundLevel($children)
{
    $level = 0;
    foreach ($children as $child) {
        $level |= $child->getNestingLevel();
    }

    return $level;
}

private function _getNeededChildLevel($child, $compoundLevel)
{
    $filter = array();
    foreach ($this->_compoundLevelFilters as $bitmask => $rules) {
        if (($compoundLevel & $bitmask) === $bitmask) {
            $filter = $rules + $filter;
        }
    }

    $realLevel = $child->getNestingLevel();
    $lowercaseType = strtolower($child->getContentType());

    if (isset($filter[$realLevel])
        && isset($filter[$realLevel][$lowercaseType]))
    {
        return $filter[$realLevel][$lowercaseType];
    } else {
        return $realLevel;
    }
}

private function _createChild()
{
    return new self($this->_headers->newInstance(),
        $this->_encoder, $this->_cache, $this->_grammar);
}

private function _notifyEncoderChanged(Swift_Mime_ContentEncoder $encoder)
{
    foreach ($this->_immediateChildren as $child) {
        $child->encoderChanged($encoder);
    }
}

private function _notifyCharsetChanged($charset)
{
    $this->_encoder->charsetChanged($charset);
    $this->_headers->charsetChanged($charset);
    foreach ($this->_immediateChildren as $child) {
        $child->charsetChanged($charset);
    }
}

private function _sortChildren()
{
    $shouldSort = false;
    foreach ($this->_immediateChildren as $child) {
        // NOTE: This include alternative parts moved into a related part
        if ($child->getNestingLevel() == self::LEVEL_ALTERNATIVE) {
            $shouldSort = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Sort in order of preference, if there is one
    if ($shouldSort) {
        usort($this->_immediateChildren, array($this, '_childSortAlgorithm'));
    }
}

private function _childSortAlgorithm($a, $b)
{
    $typePrefs = array();
    $types = array(
        strtolower($a->getContentType()),
        strtolower($b->getContentType())
        );
    foreach ($types as $type) {
        $typePrefs[] = (array_key_exists($type, $this->_alternativePartOrder))
            ? $this->_alternativePartOrder[$type]
            : (max($this->_alternativePartOrder) + 1);
    }

    return ($typePrefs[0] >= $typePrefs[1]) ? 1 : -1;
}

// -- Destructor

/**
 * Empties it's own contents from the cache.
 */
public function __destruct()
{
    $this->_cache->clearAll($this->_cacheKey);
}

/**
 * Throws an Exception if the id passed does not comply with RFC 2822.
 *
 * @param string $id
 *
 * @throws Swift_RfcComplianceException
 */
private function _assertValidId($id)
{
    if (!preg_match(
        '/^' . $this->_grammar->getDefinition('id-left') . '@' .
        $this->_grammar->getDefinition('id-right') . '$/D',
        $id
        ))
    {
        throw new Swift_RfcComplianceException(
            'Invalid ID given <' . $id . '>'
            );
    }
}
```

}

**edit *****

First i commented the getmypid(), but now sometimes I get following error

```
production.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'fopen(/tmp/4de589a57816fff756ac16f771986876/body): failed to open stream: Permission denied' in /home/ekbatana/laravel4/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/KeyCache/DiskKeyCache.php:300"
```

and I suspect that maybe the absence of getmypid() causes this

Comment: Just remove it. It's used to create a cache key, nothing more. Just don't forget. Once you touch the core code, you will have to do that every time you upgrade / update it.

Comment: switching hosts is probably the best answer... just use Laravel Forge and run on DigitalOcean or something...

Comment: I agree with @TheShiftExchange. Your new error message is easy to fix once you have more access to the server.

Answer (score 1):

you can use mt_rand(0, 32000) instead of this function.